# ASP.NET Core + Vue.JS. Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. При попытке загрузить файл на сервер выдает исключение.

Метод в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult UploadImages()
    {
        try
        {
            var data = Request.Form.Files;
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e);
        }
    }
```

Клиентская сторона:

```
uploadFiles(fileList) {
    var files = new FormData()
    files.append("file", fileList[0])

    axios.post(`/api/admin/uploadimages`, files, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Request.Form.Files всегда пустой. И я не пойму, почему. Либо не добавляется файл в FormData, либо проблема в серверной стороне.

У кого какие варианты?

Comment: Когда я писал на ASP самая отвратительная ошибка была: ValidateAntiforgeryToken, потому что просто забыть, и никаких сообщений что ошибка в этом - просто пустые данные приходили(или вообще не приходили, не помню)    - проверь, может повезет.

Comment: Не сработало. У меня даже нет предположений, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно в сигнатуре метода прописать параметры для принятия аргументов в метод. Например:

```
public IActionResult UploadImages(IFormFile file)
```

Или же это несколько файлов:

```
public IActionResult UploadImages(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
```

С последним не уверен конечно, что так будет правильно, но попробуйте.

Comment: Например:
public IActionResult UploadImages(IFormFile file)

Или же это несколько файлов:
public IActionResult UploadImages(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)

с последним не уверен конечно что так будет правильно, но попробуй, если еще актуально